# Package like react-csv that will export data into xlsx

Tags: reactjs, excel, xlsx, large-data, sheetjs

I am currently working on react-csv for exporting large data having 700000 records in csv file. react-csv is providing a CSVLink Component that will just convert whichever data into csv file. But now I need same package for converting same data into .xlsx file just like react-csv.
Is there any code exist that will just convert those large data into .xlsx file
I already tried xlsx and sheetjs-style for converting data into excel. But it's exporting only 150000 data records successfully. Its not able to convert more than 155000 data records into excel, and react-csv is only able to convert those large data into .csv files only. I am expecting a package or any component that will able to convert that large data into .xlsx file

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.